# Omniture SiteCatalyst and jQuery conflict issue

Tags: jquery, adobe-analytics

I am using a SiteCatalyst tracking script that works great without the presence of a jQuery plugin I want to use with jQuery version 1.7.1. On the contrary, of course, the jQuery plugin works fine without the presence of SiteCatalyst. I have tested and tried quite a variety of choices but all of them failed. How can I resolve this? It seems the `s` of SiteCatalyst messes things with the `$` of jQuery. Any help is highly acceptable.

Comment: Are you seeing any javascript errors?  If so, what are they?  Can you describe what you've tested so far to resolve the error?

Comment: No errors at all. The jQuery plugin i use is the backstretch plugin from here http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/. Just no image is shown as bg image as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

If you think SiteCatalyst's `s` instance is interfering with other code, get in touch with whoever in your organization is responsible in creating support tickets. Ask them to create a ticket in generating a new core javascript file with a modified tracking instance. The new instance generated by the agent is always prefixed with `s_` (e.g. `s_n` or `s_anyword`). This new tracking variable will be much less likely to have compatibility issues with your code.

Alternatively you could also use [TagManager](https://microsite.omniture.com/t2/help/en_US/sc/implement/index.html#TagManager), which allows you to define your own `s` instance, generate code, and deploy it on your site. This would not necessitate any interaction with Adobe, since you would be able to do everything within the interface.